# How does Symfony4 autowire arguments to UserPasswordEncoderCommand constructor?

Tags: symfony, symfony4

This is a question about Symfony 4 [autowiring](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html)
using only 'array' as a constructor argument type-hint.  I give a specific case, but this may be helpful to others because this situation happens in several Symfony bundles.

This Symfony command asks for a password and encodes it:
`php bin/console security:encode-password`

The code for this command is in vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Command/UserPasswordEncoderCommand.php
In Symfony 4.2.3, this is the constructor for UserPasswordEncoderCommand:

```
class UserPasswordEncoderCommand extends Command
{
    protected static $defaultName = 'security:encode-password';

    private $encoderFactory;
    private $userClasses;

    public function __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, array $userClasses = [])
    {
        $this->encoderFactory = $encoderFactory;
        $this->userClasses = $userClasses;

        parent::__construct();
    }
```

Symfony uses dependency injection to call the constructor, passing in automatically determined arguments.  The above constructor first argument $encoderFactory is autowired using the type-hint EncoderFactoryInterface.
My question is: **How is the second argument $userClasses autowired?**
How does Symfony know what the array should contain?  Debug print statements show the array contains a single value "App\Entity\User".

Here is my config/packages/security.yaml

```
security:
    encoders:
        App\Entity\User:
            algorithm: argon2i

    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        # used to reload user from session & other features (e.g. switch_user)
        app_user_provider:
            entity:
                class: App\Entity\User
                property: email
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            anonymous: true
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator

            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: true
            # https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

            logout:
                path:   app_logout
                # Where to redirect after logout
                target: app_login
```

I think the following three files are important to answering this question.
vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Resources/config/console.xml contains:

```
<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">
    <services>
        <defaults public="false" />

        <service id="security.command.user_password_encoder" class="Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Command\UserPasswordEncoderCommand">
            <argument type="service" id="security.encoder_factory"/>
            <argument type="collection" /> <!-- encoders' user classes -->
            <tag name="console.command" command="security:encode-password" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

Part of vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Resources/config/security.xml contains:

```
    <service id="security.encoder_factory" alias="security.encoder_factory.generic" />
    <service id="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\EncoderFactoryInterface" alias="security.encoder_factory" />

    <service id="security.user_password_encoder.generic" class="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoder">
        <argument type="service" id="security.encoder_factory"></argument>
    </service>

    <service id="security.password_encoder" alias="security.user_password_encoder.generic" public="true" />
    <service id="Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Encoder\UserPasswordEncoderInterface" alias="security.password_encoder" />
```

Part of vendor/symfony/security-bundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php contains:

```
function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
...
    if (class_exists(Application::class)) {
        $loader->load('console.xml');
        $container->getDefinition('security.command.user_password_encoder')->replaceArgument(1, array_keys($config['encoders']));
    }
```

---

I ask this question because I would like to use UserPasswordEncoderCommand.php as a starting point for a command to create an admin user in my database.  This will give the first admin user permission to login using the web browser to
create other users.

I tried copying vendor/symfony/security-bundle/Command/UserPasswordEncoderCommand.php to src/Command/AddUserCommand.php and changing these lines:

```
< namespace Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Command;
---
> namespace App\Command;

< class UserPasswordEncoderCommand extends Command
---
> class AddUserCommand extends Command

<     protected static $defaultName = 'security:encode-password';
---
>     protected static $defaultName = 'app:add-user';
```

When I ran this command: `php bin/console app:add-user`
this error appeared:

```
There are no configured encoders for the "security" extension.
```

This happened because the constructor __construct(EncoderFactoryInterface $encoderFactory, array $userClasses = [])
was called with only one argument, so the second argument defaulted to an empty array.

It seems these files also need to be copied from vendor/symfony/security-bundle to somewhere under src/

```
DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php
Resources/config/console.xml
```

and be somehow modified.  **Which other files need to be copied to src/ ?**  The Symfony documentation under https://symfony.com is excellent, but I can not find where this situation is described.

Note that this command works:

```
php bin/console app:add-user mypassword "App\Entity\User"
```

but I do not want the user to have to type this.  And this may change if security.yaml changes.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to do but the array of user class names is assembled in the SecurityExtension class based on your configuration data.  The service definition is then modified during a compiler pass.  For S4 the Kernel.php class can act as an extension though I'm not sure you will have access to the user class names data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case the data is being assembled by the SecurityBundle as part of the configuration process. When the kernel is booted all bundles are collected and their respective Extensions, usually inside the DependencyInjection subfolder, will be registered. When the container is built it is passed through all these extension so they can modify the services or add their own. This is how Symfony collects the configs from inside the bundle, when the main application itself does not know where they are stored, but the bundle does.

Getting the user classes is done by [`Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\DependencyInjection\SecurityExtension`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/SecurityExtension.php#L139-L146) when processing the `encoders`-section of the security.yml. If you look at the encoders section of your security.yaml you notice that each Encoder is assigned to a class name. The method will then use this array to create the appropriate encoder for the value and keep the class name as key. This array is passed to the encoder factory in `createEncoders`. Afterwards it will take the same array from the configuration, get the names of each user class using `array_keys()` and replace the argument with offset 1, i.e. the `$userClasses`, for the command.

This concept is called semantic configuration and inside your own application this would probably be overkill as you have to define the Configuration and then write the logic by hand. Instead you would probably just define an array with the class names in the parameters-section of your services.yaml.

If you want to pass in other services, which can come from other bundles your bundle does not know about, there is another approach called CompilerPasses. In a CompilerPass you can collect all classes, e.g. with a specific tag, and then pass their references to a method or the constructor of your service. This is for example used inside Symfony to register EventListeners or make Commands available in the Console application.